# 'Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data' error stops my macro from working

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to paste a large amount of data from Word or PDF to Excel for the first time I get an error saying 'Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data'. However when I cick OK and then try to paste it again, the data is pasted.

It may sound like not a big deal since I just have to press ctrl + v twice. But when I made a macro that does the exact same thing, ie. tries to paste the data, ignores the error and pastes it again it doesn't work:

```
Sub Copy()

On Error Resume Next
Sheet1.Range("A10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheet1.Range("A10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

As a result I have to run the macro twice for it to successfully paste the data (in this case only two first lines of could would be enough to make it work the same way). Do you know what I can do to paste the data with this macro by running it only once?

Comment: If you are trying to `.paste` content to several cells in one go, specifying a range of just one cell won't always work. It will either paste everything in that one cell or throw an error like here. Try to specify a range big enough to take your data, or use `.select` on your cell before using `.paste` to get around this (non-preferred method).

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` and see which errors you get. This line hides all error messages but the errors still occur. You just cannot see them. So if you don't see your errors you cannot fix them and if you don't fix them your code does not work. Never use `On Error Resume Next` without error handling!

Comment: @Plutian I have changed the code so that it pastes to the exact cell range that is requireed: `Sheet1.Range("A10:F186").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @PeterSmith without the `On Error Resume Next` it shows the exact same error ('Microsoft Excel cannot copy the data'). When I press debug and step through that line of code which caused the error, everything works and the data is pasted